# math equation with ^ wrong variables used

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm doing this equation

```
double1 * ((double2/double3) ^ 2.333)
```

getting error

> operator '`^`' cannot be used on type double`.`

what variable should I use instead of double?

Comment: ^ is __not__ Math.Pow but Logical XOR

Comment: an explanation to my ^ , im translating a vb6 program to c# so if ^ is not a correct c# var thats fine too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`Math.Pow(value, exponent)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

`Math.Pow(3,2)` outputs `9`

The operator you attempted to use (`^`) cannot be used for this purpose. It is a [logical XOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkacc7k1.aspx) and should be used for bitwise exclusive OR operations.

Comment: Additional note as to why it doesn't work with what he has: `^` is actually `XOR`.

Comment: math.pow(this would be the value i want to raise, and this would be what i want it raised by?)
so math.pow((double2/double3), 2.333) ?

Comment: @Himarm: Yes, in my example it would be `3` raised to a power of `2`.

Comment: Thanks its working as intended now.

Comment: @Himarm: Please accept my answer by clicking the checkbox to the left, to let future viewers know that this is the correct solution.

Comment: yup just waiting for the cooldown.